# How to map result from stored procedure to object

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I'm using EF for fetching data from stored procedure in MS SQL. Stored procedure is returning table. (columns have same names as properties in my object)

```
List<MyObject> result = 
              db.ExecuteStoreQuery<MyObject>("EXEC [dbo].myProcedure]").ToList();
```

Is there a way how to do this without Entity Framework? (with SqlCommand)

Thanks.

Comment: You would use ADO.NET and execute it into a DataReader and then map it to the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you could use basic ADO.NET like this:

```
var list = new List<MyObject>();
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC [dbo].myProcedure", c);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            var o = new MyObject
            {
                Property1 = sdr.GetString(0),
                Property2 = sdr.GetInt32(1),
                etc...
            }
            list.Add(o);
        }
    }
}
```

Now keep in mind that the `SqlDataReader` gets values by index, so if your `SELECT` list looked like this, `Property1, Property3, Property2`, then they would be indexed as so.

Comment: thanks, can you also recommend some automapper? Or should I map SqlDataReder into MyObject in "hard codded" way?

Comment: @Chatumbabub, I would recommend you switch your data access to [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) since you have some flexibility. It's streamlined, fast, and will auto map the objects with the query.